# Wrong sql script generated for sqlite database by ebean in the Play framework

Tags: sql, sqlite, playframework-2.0

I am using the play framework 2.1 and using the evolution to automatically generate sql scripts for me. The database I use is sqlite3.

It seems the evolution can't generate correct script for sqlite3. The incorrect script I got is:

```
create table algorithm (

id                        bigint AUTOINCREMENT primary key,

name                      varchar(255),

description               varchar(255))

;
```

I am new to sqlite3. By searching online I realized that:

1. `autoincrement` can only works with `Integer`
2. `autoincrement` should be placed after `primary key`

So obviously the automatically generated script is incorrect. My questions are:

1. Is there any way to fix the above issue so that I can still use evolution with sqlite3?
2. In general do you suggest using evolution or disable it and write sql scripts manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue yesterday. The problem is located inside the sqlite ddl configuration of the ebean framework.

However I was able to work around the problem, by creating my own implementation of the com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform.SQLitePlatform class. It's a quick hack which sets the autoincrement keyword to an empty string and redefines the bigint type to integer:

```
package com.avaje.ebean.config.dbplatform;

import java.sql.Types;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.avaje.ebean.BackgroundExecutor;

public class SQLitePlatform extends DatabasePlatform {

    static {
        System.err.println("\n\n!!! Custom SQLitePlatform class for ebean ORM loaded !!!!\n\n");
    }

    public SQLitePlatform() {
        super();
        this.name = "sqlite";

        this.dbIdentity.setIdType(IdType.IDENTITY);
        this.dbIdentity.setSupportsGetGeneratedKeys(false);
        this.dbIdentity
                .setSelectLastInsertedIdTemplate("select last_insert_rowid()");
        this.openQuote = "\"";
        this.closeQuote = "\"";

        this.booleanDbType = Types.INTEGER;

        dbTypeMap.put(Types.BIT, new DbType("int default 0"));
        dbTypeMap.put(Types.BOOLEAN, new DbType("int default 0"));
        dbTypeMap.put(Types.BIGINT, new DbType("integer"));

        dbDdlSyntax.setInlinePrimaryKeyConstraint(true);
        dbDdlSyntax.setIdentity("");
        dbDdlSyntax.setDisableReferentialIntegrity("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF");
        dbDdlSyntax.setEnableReferentialIntegrity("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
    }

    /**
     * Return null in case there is a sequence annotation.
     */
    @Override
    public IdGenerator createSequenceIdGenerator(BackgroundExecutor be,
            DataSource ds, String seqName, int batchSize) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Compile and package the class into a jar file.
When placed inside the `lib` directory of your play application, the classloader will load the class before the original implementation, and sqlite should accept the ddl generated by this custom implementation.