# What would the database tables look like if using Ebean ManyToOne relation?

Tags: sqlite, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using Ebean in the Play 2 framework. Both are quite new to me. I have two models `Algorithm` and `Solution`. (An `Algorithm` can own multiple `Solution`s.)

```
@Entity
public class Algorithm extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required    
    public String name;

    public String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="algorithm", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Solution> solutions;

    ...
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Solution extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String explanation;
    public String code;

    @ManyToOne (cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Algorithm algorithm;

    // **** I added it because the error message said algorithm_id is missing!!
    public Long algorithm_id;

    ...
}
```

I am using sqlite3 and the schema for two tables algorithm and solution are:

```
CREATE TABLE algorithm(id INTEGER primary key, name varchar(255), description varchar(255));
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE "solution"(id INTEGER primary key, explanation varchar(255), code varchar(255), algorithm_id INTEGER);
```

So in my `Solution` model, I originally didn't have the line `public Long algorithm_id;`. **The problem is** when I tried to create a new `Algorithm` instance, the play framework complained I missed a column `algorithm_id` in table `solution`. So I manually added the algorithm_id in both the model definition and the db table to make error message go away. However, it seems ebean's cascading save is not working as expected: the algorithm_id column is never filled by ebean automatically. It's always empty. In other words, the solution entity and the algorithm entity are not connected in database.

So my questions are:

1. Should I manually add algorithm_id in model and database? If not, how to make algorithm_id generated automatically?
2. What should my models and db table schemas look like in my case?

Thanks.

Comment: You can actually let Ebean generate the whole schema. Just create empty database and start application. When you will open it in a browser, Play will offer you to execute evolution script to upgrade your DB and create all missing tables. If you don't use any legacy DB structure, you can just work on models and Play will sync DB structure.

Comment: @IgorRomanov Thanks, I will try that and let you know what will happen. I disabled evolution because it seems not working with sqlite3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733941/wrong-sql-script-generated-for-sqlite-database-by-ebean-in-the-play-framework. Do you happen to know the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `algorithm_id` field from your model, when you adding `public Algorithm algorithm` - Ebean should create column in DB called `algorithm_id` but you shouldn't duplicate it in model manually.

Of course it works if you have enabled ebean plugin, if you are doing changes manually, add `algorithm_id` column to your `solution` table.

**Tip**

If you can't and/or don't want to use other DB engine, spent some time with some DB that's supported by Ebean plugin - for an example MySQL or Postgres - you will be able to check it easy with free GUIs. Create some bare project for testing purposes, create few models with relations in different directions and check how Ebean creates tables, columns, indexes, constraints etc. Keep this project for reference.

Comment: Thanks. By enabling ebean plugin do you mean enabling evolutions in play2? I disabled it because it seems it doesn't work well with sqlite3. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733941/wrong-sql-script-generated-for-sqlite-database-by-ebean-in-the-play-framework Would appreciate it if you could have a look another question I asked the other day!

Comment: In such case you need to learn proper schema building. BTW, why sqlite? Play has built-in H2 database, which at least from my observations is much faster (on my mac sqlite is really slow) and also evolution plugin works like a charm.

Comment: the reason I used sqlite is that I plan to use the database with data in it in a future iOS project. (I only need the database) Sqlite seems to be a good embedded database for iOS platform. Do you know if H2 can do the same job I want?

Comment: @ChuanRocks : check my tip if you have no possibility to use Ebean plugin, you need at least _learn_ how does it work.

Comment: I ended up using mysql and the evolution plugin works well so far. Indeed, sqlite is not a good idea for a web application.